# Why we use "this" in different styles inside the function passed to .not () and .map()?

Tags: jquery, methods, javascript-objects

Point of confusion is that, why we refer to the DOM element object using $(this) inside the function passed to .not() and this inside the function passed to .map ().

```
$('a').not (function () {return !$(this).attr ('class') == 'keep';})

$('a').map (function() {return this.class == 'keep'?  this.className : null;})
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that they are used differently? In both `this` refers to the current DOM element.

Comment: I've checked `jQuery API`, both method require DOM element, so we need use `$(this)` inside.

Comment: I have updated the question. I suddenly forgot the name map ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `this` is a DOM node, you can use either:

1. Something like `this.id` to reference a property directly on the DOM element using plain Javascript (no jQuery syntax).

or

2. Something like `$(this).css("display")` to create a jQuery object that contains your DOM element so you can then use jQuery methods with it.  `$(this)` creates a jQuery object with on element in it.

You can use either and which is more appropriate depends upon whether plain Javascript property access is all you need or whether you need a jQuery object that you can then call jQuery methods on it.  Either case be used depending upon which fits the situation.

---

FYI, in your example, you should probably be using `this.className`, not `this.class`.  Note from MDN:

> The name `className` is used for this property instead of `class` because
>   of conflicts with the "class" keyword in many languages which are used
>   to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. A confusion, do you mean the wrapper object ("jQuery object that contain your DOM element) :)

Comment: @Devashish - A jQuery object is sometimes call a "wrapper object" since it's a Javascript object that contains a list of DOM objects.  Other than that explanation, I'm not sure what else you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your code? Both callbacks are passed plain DOM nodes, so you will need to use `$()` in both if you want to use jQuery functions such as `attr`.